# How can I get to this chest past this iceblock puzzle?

Tags: ittle-dew

I found a little cave with a chest in it. For obvious reasons I want to loot that chest (chests *need* to be looted).

I know I have to push one of the iceblocks onto the yellow/orange-ish switch. I can break a block of ice or push a single block, which will then glide until it hits a wall/other block of ice.

In what order do I have to break/push the blocks to get one on the button? Or do I need to return later when I have unlocked more skills/options?

[image: puzzle-setup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by breaking either the top right or top left block (it doesn't matter which). Push the remaining top block right to the doorway and then push it down so that it's level with the other two blocks.

Next push one of the other two blocks all the way to the top (again, it doesn't matter which), then push it all the way to the right.

From there, push the final block right, then up, then left to land it on top of the switch.

Answer (score 5):

The answer, now in picture form (violet, red, yellow, green in that order).

[image: Dew]

Comment: I was contemplating some ASCII art, but this is clearer.